# Change language in android application after publication

Tags: java, android, google-play, wrapper, android-context

After loading into the play market, the languages cannot be changed, although everything worked fine on the device and emulator. I came to the conclusion that Google blocks languages and reloads only when changing the system language, is this the reason? If so, how can you manually query or bypass them?

And the class itself responsible for this looks like this:

```
public class MyContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {

public MyContextWrapper(Context base) {
    super(base);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, String language) {
    Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    Locale sysLocale = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        sysLocale = getSystemLocale(config);
    } else {
        sysLocale = getSystemLocaleLegacy(config);
    }
    if (!language.equals("") && !sysLocale.getLanguage().equals(language)) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            setSystemLocale(config, locale);
        } else {
            setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
        }
    }
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Language.setLang(language);
    return new MyContextWrapper(context);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config) {
    return config.locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config) {
    return config.getLocales().get(0);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
    config.locale = locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
    config.setLocale(locale);
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, Language.getLang()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deliver a bundle, instead of a apk, please add this code block into app `build.gradle`

```
android {
 ...
 bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}
```

refer [Re-enable or disable types of configuration APKs](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/configure-base#disable_config_apks)